# Apex : Table where static application files are stored?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Oracle 11 running Apex 19.2.

Does anyone know the tables where static application files are stored ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select * from apex_workspace_static_files;
select * from apex_application_static_files;

select * from APEX_190200.APEX_APPLICATION_STATIC_FILES;
```